# Creating records based on value in a cell

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that gives an overview of total # of sales, and I need to create a table with individual (repeating) records based on the values.

For example  see table 1

```
| Date   | ID   | Metric       | Response | Value |
|--------|------|--------------|----------|-------|
| Feb 19 | abc1 | Sell Product | Yes      | 3     |
| Feb 19 | abc1 | Sell Product | Total    | 4     |
```

Comment: You have shown one table.  Is this the input, or the output, and can you show the table which is missing?

Comment: Please add the following two details: (1) Your Oracle version; (2) The level of expertise at which you need to solve this problem. For example, I can post an answer using the LATERAL clause; but that is only available since version 12.1, and it won't help you if this requirement is in an introductory SQL course (if you present a LATERAL solution your teacher will know you didn't come up with it).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question:

```
SQL> with table1 (c_date, id, metric, response, value) as
  2    (select 'Feb 19', 'abc1', 'Sell Product', 'Yes'  , 3 from dual union all
  3     select 'Feb 19', 'abc1', 'Sell Product', 'Total', 4 from dual
  4    )
  5  select c_date, id, metric, response, value
  6  from table1 join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  7                                       connect by level <= value
  8                                      ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) on 1 = 1;

C_DATE ID   METRIC       RESPO      VALUE
------ ---- ------------ ----- ----------
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Yes            3
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Yes            3
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Yes            3
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Total          4
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Total          4
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Total          4
Feb 19 abc1 Sell Product Total          4

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

(Dates are *strings* in this example, but it doesn't really matter - if the general idea is acceptable to you).